# Retrieving data from OleDb query not displaying in MessageBox

Tags: c#, forms

I get no exception errors with the below code which could mean there is no problem with my sql statement. However upon trying to verify if it returns any value, i pass the returned items to a string value and try to display it in a message box.

the problem am facing is the message box only displays the name of the column and not the data ive requested from the table.

what could possibly be the problem? and please advice if theres a better way to work around this...

```
    public void DisplayPurchase(OleDbConnection mDB)
    {
        openDB();
        string sqlQuery;
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        OleDbDataReader rdr;



        sqlQuery = "SELECT CustomerTable.[Youth ID], CustomerTable.Firstname, " +
            "CustomerTable.Lastname, Youth.Purchaseid, Youth.NumbersOfSport, " + 
            "Youth.Price, Youth.TotalCostOfTraining, Youth.PercentageDiscount, " +
            "Youth.AmountDue, Youth.DatePurchased" +
            " FROM CustomerTable, Youth WHERE Youth.YouthID = CustomerTable.[Youth ID]" +
            " AND CustomerTable.[Youth ID] = 7";

        try
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, mDB);

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                qtyInt1 = (int)rdr["Youth.NumbersOfSport"];
                youthInt1 = (int)rdr["CustomerTable.[Youth ID]"];
                firstStr1 = (string)rdr["CustomerTable.Firstname"];
                purStr1 = (string)rdr["Youth.Purchaseid"];
                lastStr1 = (string)rdr["CustomerTable.Lastname"];
                priceStr1 = (string)rdr["Youth.Price"];
                totalCstStr1 = (string)rdr["Youth.TotalCostOfTraining"];
                discountStr1 = (string)rdr["Youth.PercentageDiscount"];
                amtDueStr1 = (string)rdr["Youth.AmountDue"];
                //purDate1 = (DateTime)rdr["Youth.DatePurchased"];

                MessageBox.Show(firstStr1.ToString());

                closeDB();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Reader has no rows");
                closeDB();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the declaration of firstStr1?  I suppose it's not a string, since you're calling ToString() on it

Comment: {
        //Declare connection to database as mDb
        public static OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();

        //variable declarations
        int qtyInt1;
        int youthInt1;
        int youthInt;
        string priceStr1;
        string totalCstStr1;
        string discountStr1;
        string amtDueStr1;
        string firstStr1;
        string purStr1;
        string lastStr1;
        DateTime purDate1;
        float horizontalPrintLocationfloat;
        float verticalPrintLocationfloat;

       
 i added the declarations so you can see i declared it as a string

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that you have to call rdr.Read() before you can access any data from it. So, add that as the first line after if(rdr.HasRows())

Comment: Yes you do have to call `rdr.Read()`.

Comment: As a test, try this code:  
  
firstStr1 = (string)rdr["CustomerTable.Firstname"].ToString()  
  
What does it return?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call Read() on the reader to *read* the first row.

```
if(rdr.HasRows) {
    rdr.Read();
    ...
```

Best wishes,
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
firstStr1 = (string)rdr["Firstname"];
```

The fieldname in a datareader typically does not include the tablename prefix.

Comment: I tried that earlier on and i get the error message" Unable to cast object of type'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'. am i parsing a string to an int value? but i crossed checked with the properties in my database and its just the youthid and numberOfSports that take on number values, everything else is in text. so what could be causing this error?

Comment: You did add the `reader.Read()` call right?  If so, break in the debugger and add `rdr["Firstname"]` to the watch list.  This should show you the content of the Firstname column

Answer (score 0):

Remove the table names when you are retrieving the data:

```
qtyInt1 = (int)rdr["NumbersOfSport"];
youthInt1 = (int)rdr["Youth ID"];  // You may need to rename this one in the query
firstStr1 = (string)rdr["Firstname"];
purStr1 = (string)rdr["Purchaseid"];
lastStr1 = (string)rdr["Lastname"];
priceStr1 = (string)rdr["Price"];
totalCstStr1 = (string)rdr["TotalCostOfTraining"];
discountStr1 = (string)rdr["PercentageDiscount"];
amtDueStr1 = (string)rdr["AmountDue"];
```

Comment: I tried that earlier on and i get the error message" Unable to cast object of type'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'. am i parsing a string to an int value? but i crossed checked with the properties in my database and its just the youthid and numberOfSports that take on number values, everything else is in text. so what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Its amazing how this stuff works...
Id firstly like to thank everybody that contributed to solving this problem.Am really grateful for every alphabet posted.

sqlQuery = "SELECT Youth.YouthID,  Firstname, Lastname, NumbersOfSport, Price, TotalCostOFTraining, PercentageDiscount, Purchaseid, AmountDue, DatePurchased FROM CustomerTable, Youth WHERE CustomerTable.YouthID = Youth.YouthID AND Youth.YouthID = "+ toSql(youthInt);

```
        try
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, mDB);

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                rdr.Read();
                qtyInt1 = (int)rdr["NumbersOfSport"];
                youthInt1 = (int)rdr["YouthID"];
                firstStr1 = (string)rdr["Firstname"];
                purInt1 = (int)rdr["Purchaseid"];
                lastStr1 = (string)rdr["Lastname"];
                priceStr1 = (string)rdr["Price"];
                totalCstStr1 = (string)rdr["TotalCostOfTraining"];
                discountStr1 = (string)rdr["PercentageDiscount"];
                amtDueStr1 = (string)rdr["AmountDue"];
                purDate1 = (DateTime)rdr["DatePurchased"];



                closeDB();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Reader has no rows");
                closeDB();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

I had to call for the rdr.read(); functions as well as taking of the table referencing on the database columns and each help came from a different sources.....
thats awesome...
Thanks everybody...